# How to write a modulino in zsh?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, modulino

I like to write my scripts as "modulinos", shell scripts that can be called by themselves as little CLI programs, or imported by other programs as libraries.

I can do this in bash with:

https://github.com/mcandre/scriptedmain/tree/master/bash

And I would like to do this in zsh as well. How could I do this?

The most important thing is to find a way to emulate bash's:

```
if [[ "$BASH_SOURCE" == "$0" ]]
then
    main
fi
```

In other words, find the name of *this* script vs the name of the summoned program (when they're equal, run main(), when they're different, skip, because this script is being imported as a library).

The trouble is, I think zsh's `$0` behaves like bash's `$BASH_SOURCE`, and I don't think there's a zsh equivalent to bash's `$0` (which works differently) to compensate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the value of the last element of `zsh_eval_context`. If it equals "toplevel", that should be equivalent to the `$BASH_SOURCE == $0` check being true.

```
if [[ $zsh_eval_context[-1] == toplevel ]]; then
    main
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, dude! Works perfectly on my machine!